# From where does "ps" on Android get user names?

Tags: linux, shell, ps, android

I have an Android tablet that I got a terminal program from Google Play Store. When I issue the "ps" command, it shows various names for the users running the processes. There is no /etc/passwd file on this machine so I'm wondering where it gets the user names from.

Answer (score 5):

`ps` will get the names with the `getpwuid(3)` function (see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/toybox/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/toys/posix/ps.c#510)).

On android, that will generate pwd entries [on the fly](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/libc/bionic/grp_pwd.cpp#468), rather than fetching them from some file.